# LoadRunner picking up 3 values in xml response

Tags: iteration, response, loadrunner

Having a response to my request loooking like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <ns3:hentDokumentForventningerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://nav.no/tjeneste/virksomhet/henvendelse/v1/informasjon" xmlns:ns3="http://nav.no/tjeneste/virksomhet/henvendelsesbehandling/v1">
     <dokumentForventning>
        <id>525</id>
        <kodeverkId>kodeForDagpenger</kodeverkId>
        <innsendingsValg>IKKE_VALGT</innsendingsValg>
        <hovedskjema>true</hovedskjema>
     </dokumentForventning>
     <dokumentForventning>
        <id>526</id>
        <kodeverkId>kodeForEgetVedlegg</kodeverkId>
        <innsendingsValg>IKKE_VALGT</innsendingsValg>
        <hovedskjema>false</hovedskjema>
        <friTekst>Oppsigelse</friTekst>
     </dokumentForventning>
     <dokumentForventning>
        <id>524</id>
        <kodeverkId>kodeForPermitteringsvarsel</kodeverkId>
        <innsendingsValg>IKKE_VALGT</innsendingsValg>
        <hovedskjema>false</hovedskjema>
     </dokumentForventning>
  </ns3:hentDokumentForventningerResponse>
```

I want to save all the 3 id-values (525, 526, 524) in LoadRunner.
How do I do that?
In SoapUI I would typically write:
[image: soapui]

Comment: Using "Ord=All" gives me the 3 values as param1_1, param1_2, param1_3. 
How do I refer the value for param1_1, pram1_2 and so forth in my next request?

Answer (score 0):

Using "Ord=All" and referencing these values with _1, _2, _3 in my next request works fine. Solved this myself!